# Random lines when loading a TopoJSON file in D3

Tags: d3.js, shapefile, topojson

I'm trying to display the Italian cartographic shapefiles, [for example this one](http://www.istat.it/storage/basi_territoriali_2013/LimitiAmministrativi/Limiti2011/Reg2011_ED50.zip), using D3.js

I can load the Zip file on [MapShaper](http://mapshaper.org/), look at the map, simplify it and export to TopoJSON. I can load back the TopoJSON in MapShaper and it still looks ok.

But when I try to display it using D3.js, I get a bunch of spaghetti:

[image]

Beauty, isn't it?

The code is taken straight from the examples. The projection center, rotation, and parallels are supposed to be the canonical ones for Italy, but it doesn't really matter: the map remains spaghetti-like with any choice of projection.

```
width = 600
height = 1200

projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center [0, 41]
    .rotate [347, 0]
    .parallels [35, 45]
    .scale 2000
    .translate [width / 2, height / 2]

path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection projection

svg = d3.select "body"
    .append "svg"
    .attr "width", width
    .attr "height", height

d3.json "Reg2011_ED50.json", (json) ->
    svg.append "path"
        .datum topojson.feature json, json.objects.Reg2011_ED50
        .attr "d", path
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Getting a bunch of spaghetti when rendering a map of Italy isn't that far of, huh? Made my day ;-) Anyway, could you provide a live demo including the exported TopoJSON to fiddle around with?

Comment: @altocumulus Thank you, but I found the solution, even though I don't understand it.

Comment: It's because you didn't specify the projection. This is pretty normal.

Comment: @kwoxer I did create a projection object and set the path object to it. What else should I have done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an old mailing list post detailing how to import those exact files.

Basically I needed to convert the projection to a standard one with this command:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 converted.shp original.shp
```

I don't understand why it's needed: I thought the `.prj` file took care of projection differences. Apparently not.